# Suppose that the ODE $x'=f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded, $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all x

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that no solution of the ODE escapes to infinity in finite time.

What I've gotten so far is:

$x' = \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)$. And, $-M \leq \frac{dx}{dt} \leq M$. Thus, by integrating, $|x(t)| \leq Mt$.

$x(t)$ will go to infinity as $t$ goes to infinity, but is a correct proof?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is almost correct. Integrating $-M \leq {dx \over dt} \leq M$ from $0$ to $t$ leads to
$$-Mt \leq x(t) - x(0) \leq Mt$$
This is the same as
$$-Mt + x(0) \leq x(t) \leq Mt + x(0)$$
So $x(t)$ doesn't blow up in finite time. Since $x(t) = 0$ satisfies the conditions $x(t)$ doesn't have to blow up at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. It shows that the solution is bounded on any bounded interval, and as a consequence, it is global (i.e., defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$.)

However, your conclusion that $x(t)$ goes to $\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ is not correct. $x$ may be bounded, as the case $f(x)=\sin x$ shows.